# Modify dynamic distribution lists in a bulk - Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010, distribution-lists

We have a situation here. So, basically our users right now are in the group abc>users will be migrated to a new OU like abc>country>users. This will affect several dynamic distribution groups with the old filter.

Normally, when we created our dynamic distribution group, we set a filter like this:

> Set-DynamicDistributionGroup list1 -RecipientFilter {((((((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Manager -like 'CN=Manager1,OU=USERS,OU=abc,DC=europe,DC=corp,DC=ad,DC=com'))) -or (DisplayName -like 'Surname Name'))) -and (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')) -and (-not(Name -like 'CAS_{*')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'MailboxPlan')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')))}

This list contains all the users that have a Manager called Manager1

The problem is that we have to modify more than 300 lists, which means every list has their own Manager.

How can we proceed with this?

Comment: You can try to export the dynamic distribution list with filter info to a csv file, then search and replace the ou, last export the csv use foreach to set the dynamic distribution group again.